# BigQuery API - Unable to connect Remote Server

Tags: c#-4.0, google-bigquery

Am able to access bigquery api and able to get data by running queries through C#, but when i try the same from other machine am not able to get data. I get access token but while executing query i get exception With Message - "Unable to connect Remote Server" and Inner Exeption as - "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced".

Is there anything i need to do for accessing API from multiple machines during development.I tried using two different clentId and Secret keys for both machines, still didnt work.

Please help.

stack trace

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.EndAttachBody(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CaptureOrComplete(ExecutionContext& cachedContext, Boolean returnContext)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.FinishPostingAsyncOp()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.AttachBody(WebRequest request, Action`1 onRequestReady)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.CreateWebRequest(Action`1 onRequestReady)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.ExecuteRequestAsync(Action`1 responseHandler)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetAsyncResponse(Action`1 responseHandler)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetResponse()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.Fetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

No - there's nothing you need to do when testing from multiple machines in general.

Try browsing to https://bigquery.cloud.google.com from the machine which cannot connect.  This uses the same underlying API.  Or try using the APIs explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/.

Retrieving an access token and executing a query are done on different hosts.  Most likely scenario is that you have a firewall blocking outbound requests to unknown servers.

Comment: Thanks Ryan,We are not using any firewall. and am able to run queries using BigQuery Browser tool web interface. and also i can browse API Explorer. But When i do the same through C# its not working.

Comment: Do you need to go through a proxy, or do you have a direct connection?  I'd suggest trying to make a HTTP request to a random website (say stackoverflow.com) from within your C# code and see if that's possible.  Also suggest adding your full stacktrace into your question above.

Comment: No we are not going through any proxy. And as u suggested i tried accessing some random website from C# and its possible.And i have edited question to include stacktrace.